# Delete git branches on server

Tags: git, git-branch

how can I delete this two branches:

- remotes/main/main
- remotes/main/HEAD

[CMD result of git branch -vaa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug6KX.png)

The remotes/origin/... branches are correct.

I tried:

`git push origin -d main/main`
-> error: unable to delete 'main/main': remote ref does not exist

`git push main -d main`
-> fatal: 'main' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the branch actually exist on the remote or are you just trying to delete the local reference?

To delete the local reference:

```
git branch -rd main/main
```